# How to save a file from Dropbox link in my Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

If my client choose a file from Dropbox using Dropbox Chooser and we have a link like https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/og7hvjnt7p57jjw/Penguins.jpg. Now if client removes file from his Dropbox account we have nothing so my question is  how can I add this file to my Dropbox using PHP instead of Dropbox Saver?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-save-a-file-in-my-dropbox-from-dropbox-shared-link/m-p/192814 ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal HTTP GET request to download the file from the link while the link is still valid. (Note, the "direct" link type you have in your question [expires after four hours](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#js).)

Then, you can use the Dropbox API to upload the file to your own Dropbox account:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload